# Hammerjs with touch emulator not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hammer.js

I've been trying to test and emulate touch events using Hammerjs in React, but with extremely inconsistent behavior between browsers and events.

Let's take simple code like:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Hammer from 'hammerjs';
import touchEmulator from 'hammer-touchemulator';

function testTap() {
  console.log('test zoom');
}

function testPinch() {
  console.log('test pinch');
}

class PDF extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      touchEmulator();
      ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.hammer = Hammer(this.canvas);
    this.hammer.on('tap', testTap);
    this.hammer.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
    this.hammer.on('pinch', testPinch);
  }

  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas
          ref={(canvas) => { this.canvas = canvas; }}
        />
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

I added the touch emulator so I can test pinch zooming.

So here are my problems:

- Tap doesn't work when touch emulator is enabled, but works fine without in Chrome and Firefox
- I tried the pinch zoom on [Hammerjs's](http://hammerjs.github.io/#try-it) site and this works in Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome.  When I try it locally in my React app it doesn't work on any of these.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, so for swipe switched to `react-swipeable`, but `react-hammerjs` leaved for tap.
Also while searching for solution saw one article where someone mentioned, that some features are disabled since React 16.4, You can try to downgrade React version and then check it out if is the case.